# SVN:// protocol stopped working after migration of Active directories for the authz file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So we did a ldap migration, so we had to swap out the old usernames within the authz file to their new usernames within the active directory. did those changes, commited it back to the repo, and everyone can log in now with their credentials. The only problem now, is the svn:// protocol doesnt work anymore....http:// still does. Just curious in terms of why or if anyone knows how to fix this issue. The error I recieve is E170001 unable to connect to a repo at URL " " SASL authentication failure.

httpd:// protocol still works with the new active directory credentials, but the svn:// protocol doesnt, but works with the old active directory credentials.. even though i have updated the saslauth.conf file to the new ldap

Answer (score 0):

ahh solved the issue,

just needed to service saslauthd restart

fixed my issue!:P=